# Ember.js adapter/serializer configuration for legacy API

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to get a new Ember 2.2 application to talk to a legacy API server. I can not change server code so trying to figure out how to customise Ember Data to handle the models well.

The issue is that server APIs return a JSON like this for every kind of models:

```
{ content: [ {id: 1, title: "a"}, {id: 2, title: "b"}, meta: {...} ]
```

I would use `JSONAPISerializer` if the server used a different root for each model instead of the `content` key. I would use `JSONSerializer` if the response was just a plain array (i.e. no `content` key in it at all). But I do not see a way to get it to work with the response above.

What would be your suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to implement the [`normalize`](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html#method_normalize) method and the related methods as necessary in order to pre-process your JSON so that it conforms to a standard format. In this case you can strip away the `content` wrapper in order to get the JSON into a format that will work with the `JSONSerializer`.